# How to change label font with changing custom property grid in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, label, propertygrid

I have a label and a property grid that I customized that property grid, but changing the font in the property grid does not change the label font and I do not know how to link it to the label.
this is class for custom property grid:

```
Public Class GridSetting
    Private _LabelFont As System.Drawing.Font
 
    <CategoryAttribute("Design"), DefaultValueAttribute(""),
DescriptionAttribute("Select font for the Label")>
    Public Property LabelFont() As System.Drawing.Font

        Get
            Return _LabelFont

        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As System.Drawing.Font)
            _LabelFont = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and this is my cod:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = New GridSetting

End Sub
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If I understood what you need, you gonna need to implement the [IExtenderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider?view=net-5.0) interface for this one.

Comment: @dr.null Dear dr.null, Thank you very much for your help.it helped me a lot. You are the best.

Comment: What Label are you referring to? There are no Labels in that code. Also, you're passing a new `GridSetting` object to the PropertyGrid, hence it's not *linked* to any other Control by any form of binding.

Comment: @Jimi Yes exactly, I added this line of cod ```Form1.Label1.Font = Value``` into ```Set(ByVal Value As System.Drawing.Font)``` in class. Thank you dear jimi

Comment: @jimi and I added ```_LabelFont=Form1.Label1.Font``` into ```get``` to get the label font.

Comment: You need simple binding. E.g., `Private grdSettings As GridSetting = New GridSetting() '[...] SomeLabel.DataBindings.Add("Font", grdSettings, "LabelFont", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged) PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = grdSettings` -- Don't use, in any case, ever, default Form instances to refer to child Controls. Or default Form instances in general. Always build a **new Instance**: `dim f1 as new Form1() f1.Show()`, then use the `f1` instance, when / if needed. -- You haven't described the use of your GridSettings or defined its scope...

Comment: @Jimi WOW, that's great This is very professional, it will definitely do the same. Thank you so much for help. You are the best, Dear jimi.